# Regex pattern to match hashtag, but not in HTML attributes

Tags: html, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to **extract hashtags in an HTML text** with the regular expression `#([a-z0-9_]+)`, but with troubles in HTML attributes.

For example in the HTML text:

```
hola que tal with #hash1.
hola que tal with #hash2

y <a href="hola.que.tal#hash3"> para #hash4. </a>
```

I want to recover "hash1", "hash2" and "hash4" but **not** "hash3".

I tried to resolve it with lookarounds, with the following expression:

```
(?<!<)#([a-z0-9_]+)(?!.*?>)
```

but without success.

How I can do it with a **single regular expression**?

Comment: Use an html parser and eventually an xpath query to target only text nodes. Then use a basic regex to find your hashtags for each text node.

Comment: I know I can do it in several steps, but I need to do it with a single regular expression. Thanks @CasimiretHippolyte

Comment: Why do you want to do it with just one step (regular expression)?

Comment: I try to maintain the code in all the calls that depends on it.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to post a solution, José. If the solution you wish to post is substantially different from Chris' below, then please make your own answer. However if you just want to thank Chris for their answer, then please click the tick mark to the left of their post - it will turn green, and mark the question as resolved. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'm still a newbie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
/#[a-z0-9_]+(?![^<]*>)/
```

See http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=95144

What the negative lookahead does is makes sure that there is a `<` between the hashtag and the next `>`.

Comment: Great regex. I enclose the result cause I need to capture the result. Edited with your solution. Thanks!